# How to set error.name in extended class Error in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to set the error name `err.name = 'ExpressValidatorError';`

of an custom Error class `class AppError extends Error`

that is passed to centralErrorHandler to filter and handle errors by `err.name`.

I have did a lot of research but still couldn't figure out why `err.name` in centralErrorHandler console logs as `undefined`.

When I change `return next(err);` in auth.controller.js to `throw err;`, the `err.name` does console log as `'ExpressValidatorError'` but i'm not sure if using throw is correct.

centralErrorHandler.js

```
module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {    
 err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
 err.status = err.status || 'error';   
      
 let error = {...err};

 console.log(error.name);

 if(err.name === 'ExpressValidatorError') error = handleExpressValidatorError(err);    

 if(err.name === 'InternalOAuthError') error = handleInternalOAuthError(err);    

 res.status(error.statusCode).json({
   status: error.status,            
   message: error.message            
 });  
}
```

auth.controller.js

```
const {validationResult} = require('express-validator');

exports.signup = (req, res) => {     
    const errors = validationResult(req); 
   
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        let err = new AppError(`Invalid login credentials.`, 422);
        err.name = 'ExpressValidatorError';            
             
        return next(err);
      }

    res.status(200).send(req.user);          
}
```

appError.js

```
class AppError extends Error {
    constructor(message, statusCode){
        super(message);

        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.status = `${statusCode}`.startsWith('4') ? 'fail' : 'error';        
        this.isOperational = true;        

        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    }
}

module.exports = AppError;
```

Comment: It seem working fine on my local, what is your nodejs version?

Comment: Hi, here are the version details: 
`"engines": {
    "node": "12.18.1",
    "npm": "6.14.5"
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set the property name like this:

```
class AppError extends Error {
    constructor(message, statusCode, name){
        super(message);
        this.name = name;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.status = `${statusCode}`.startsWith('4') ? 'fail' : 'error';        
        this.isOperational = true;        

        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    }
}

module.exports = AppError;
```

This way the property name will be bound to the object of AppError.

And middleware like this:

```
const {validationResult} = require('express-validator');

exports.signup = (req, res, next) => {     
    const errors = validationResult(req); 
   
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        let err = new AppError(`Invalid login credentials.`, 422);
        err.name = 'ExpressValidatorError';            
             
        return next(err);
      }

    res.status(200).send(req.user);          
}
```

Comment: Hi, i tried that `let err = new AppError('Invalid login credentials.', 422, 'ExpressValidatorError');` but don't know why the `error.name` passed to the centralErrorHandler still console log as `undefined`.

Comment: That shouldn't be can you please try consoling `err` and then try consoling the `error` object itself I'm a little sceptic that data might be getting lost while `{...err}`

Comment: when i `console.log(err);` in centralErrorHandler, it returns  ReferenceError: next is not defined. You are right, the err object is lost when it reach centralErrorHandler.js

Comment: Updated the answer to explicitly include next can you please try that now?

Comment: sorry but i cannot see the update, can you explain on which part is updated to explicitly include next?

Comment: `exports.signup = (req, res, next) => {     ` this line

Comment: it does fix the whole issue. `err.name = 'ExpressValidatorError'; ` works fine without the need of constructor.